# Use Jrebel to remote debug a spring boot app?

Tags: java, debugging, intellij-idea, jrebel

I have a "legacy" Java 8 app that contains 15 years worth of code.    I need to debug using JRebel to shorten the change times as I make modifications.   I am using IntelliJ 23.1.2 and Jrebel 2023.2.2.

I have to run this app outside Intellij and debug as a "Remote JVM App" in Intellij to debug it because it will not run directly out of the build directory.

The JRebel instructions say that I should be able to remote-debug this app, but if I run the app in a command window then select my "Debug" configuration to connect to the JVM in IntelliJ the "Jrebel" debug icon is not lit up so I cannot run the Intellij features simultaneously with the Jrebel features (see screenshot).   What am I missing here?

[image: Intellij options]

Here is my Java run command, I include the Intellij agentlib parameter for remote debugging and the JRebel parameters for JRebel functionality.

Any help is appreciated.

```
java -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=5005  "-agentpath:C:\jrebel\lib\jrebel64.dll" -Drebel.remoting_plugin=true -jar myapp.war
```